# SP Online: 'Search and offline availability' setting missing under Site Settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

This is very strange issue, I used to have option of **'Search and offline availability'** under Site Settings, but suddenly it got disappeared.

[image]

**Details:**

**Site:** SharePoint Online

**Permission**: Site Collection Administrator & Site Owner

Any reason for this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This settings also is missing at my SharePoint Online sites. I searched online and was unable to find anything about it.

Anyway, if you want to use this feature, you can access it via appending **_layouts/15/srchvis.aspx** to the URL of your site:

```
https://yoursite/_layouts/15/srchvis.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks Kally, yes I am using same URL to Re-Index the site. I just wanted to check the reason for this change and if their is any change with the search which may impact search result .

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue by Microsoft and is now being mitigated.